# Web API OAuth external login without using any Asp.Net Identity tables?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

I am developing an AngularJS application with some Asp.Net Core Web API support. This application is not using any database in backend. Now I want to implement a social login option for some privileged access. What is the best authentication mechanism without using any Asp.Net Identity tables?

As far I know OpenIddict is coupled with Asp.Net Identity So that I must implement a storage mechanism for that. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am also looking for other options like ASOS but it is too complicated compared to OpenIddict so I couldn't find a good solution with that.

Kevin Chalet published an excellent article but still I am struggling because of my poor technical knowledge on this subject.

http://kevinchalet.com/2016/07/13/creating-your-own-openid-connect-server-with-asos-introduction/

Can you please guid me?

Comment: FYI: OpenIddict is no longer tied to ASP.NET Core Identity, which means you can use it with your own membership stack. I blogged about that recently: http://kevinchalet.com/2017/01/30/implementing-simple-token-authentication-in-aspnet-core-with-openiddict/